# javascript - ajax done() callback return - not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function validateURL(url) {
     if(url){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/check_urlstatus/",
            type: "post",
            data: {url:url,csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}                  
        }).done(function(data){
           if(data=="ok"){
             return true;
           }else{
             return false;
           }
        });       
     }else{
         return false;
     }       
 }

function check(){
  var web = $.trim($('#web').val());   
  var status = validateURL(web);
  alert(status); 
}
```

ajax is returning `ok` String. But this alert inside `check()` is giving `undefined`. I guess, the scope of `.done()` callback is local?! or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @dfsq oh thanks man. didnot see it

Comment: You are welcome. Short answer: you cannot return from asynchronous operations, because response is not yet available. So you use callback or deferred/promise pattern instead.

Comment: @dfsq wonderful! finally learnt something new today!